# Extend Google Maps + D3 example to add a path or line

Tags: javascript, google-maps, d3.js

I am trying to modify this [Google Maps + D3 example](http://bl.ocks.org/1125458)  to include lines between points.  The approach I took was to add new svg elements for each line.

I've managed to create a new set of svg elements:

```
var markerLink = layer.selectAll(".links")
      .data(links)
      .each(pathTransform) // update existing markers
    .enter().append("line")
      .each(pathTransform)
      .attr("class", "links");
```

Where links is an array of arrays.  Each inner array has 4 values corresponding to  latitude and longitude of the beginning and end of each line: x1, y1, x2 and y2 of the d3 line.

The pathTransform function:

```
function pathTransform(d) {
    var t, b, l, r, w, h;
    var d1 = new google.maps.LatLng(d[1], d[0]);
    var d2 = new google.maps.LatLng(d[3], d[2]);
    d1 = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(d1);
    d2 = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(d2);
    if ( d1.y < d2.y ) {
      t = d1.y - 25;
      b = d2.y + 25;
    } else {
      t = d2.y - 25;
      b = d1.y + 25;
    }
    if ( d1.x < d2.x ) {
      l = d1.x - 25;
      r = d2.x + 25;
    } else {
      l = d2.x - 25;
      r = d1.x + 25; 
    }

    return d3.select(this)
        .style("left", l + "px")
        .style("top", t + "px")
        .style("width", (r - l) + "px")
        .style("height", (b - t) + "px");
  }
```

takes the latitude and longitude values and returns a properly sized and positioned svg element.

Following the example with the marker svg elements, I tried to append a line to the markerLink elements. This is where I run into trouble. I can't figure out how to position the lines within each svg.

Is this a good approach or is there another way to add circles, paths, lines and labels to google map overlays?

Comment: check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622484/d3-graph-with-links-over-google-maps). Your code is slightly different but you can adapt it and post your own answer. Cheers.