# List of coordinates -> Polyline along the roads -> kml output

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This being my first question, please ignore any gaffes.

I have a dataset containing >2000 bus routes, each with >20 bus stops with their latlongs. The final goal is to have kml files , one for each route.

I started with plotting the network diagram as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622484/d3-graph-with-links-over-google-maps) easily plotted maps like [these](https://googledrive.com/host/0B-SxilqpsaHTOEVJblYwb0pzVWc/allthreeoverlaid.html).

Question 1: Instead of straight lines connecting two bus stops, ideally it should follow the roads. What is the approach to do this? Also, I understand that there is a limit on the number of waypoints in the v3 API free version, so how do I plot more than 8 points in a route?

Question 2: How can these network diagrams be exported to kml or shp files?

(Side question: How can I toggle the display/order of a particular route maybe using a checkbox?)

Thanks in advance!!

(I only have intermediate level/copy-paste programming skills)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rAs you have stated your skills are copy and paste.  I'm not sure this will be much good to you but I will endeavour to help anyhow.

**QUESTION 1:**  Unless you have a dataset with many many points in, your only option to plot the routes along the road is to use the Google Maps API Direction Requests.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

You are correct in only being able to add 8 waypoints per request, however this does not stop you making multiple requests.  You can make up to ten requests a second each with 8 waypoints.    If you exceed this you'll get a error of a type that means you have exceeded the limit.  You can trap this error (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DirectionsStatus) and then pause your code for a moment (using javascript settimeout) and then make another 80 requests.  You can continue until you reach the the end of your route.

**QUESTION 2:**  This is difficult to answer as I don't know what you mean by network diagrams or what form these take.

You might find some useful information here: https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut

**SIDE QUESTION:** There are number of options.  If you want to switch between routes a dropdown list would be the way forward.  If you wanted to display multiple routes and be able to switch them on and off, than a checkbox list would probably suit.  I personally would probably use a floating div to house the contents of such controls.

Hope you get at least something from this.